# Как удалить кэш поста при обновлении?

Tags: кэширование, ruby-on-rails

Пытаюсь сделать умное кэширование постов в блоге, дабы уменьшить время загрузки страниц, но оно не работает: кэш создаётся один раз и более не обновляется.

```
# posts/show.html.slim
#кэшировать пост как фрагмент с именем вида post-xxx. Если такого фрагмента в кэше нет,
# то сервер отрисует его и закэширует, иначе -- загрузит из кэша.
- cache "post-#{@post.id}" do
  = render @post
  = link_to 'Back', journal_path

class ToolsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    case params[:type] 
    when "post"
      @journal = @post.journal
      respond_to do |format|
        if @post.update(post_params)
          # При обновлении поста удаляем соответствующий ему фрагмент из кэша.
          # При следующем открытии поста кэш будет создан снова.
          expire_fragment('post-#{@post.id}') 
          flash.notice = "Post successfully updated"
          format.html { render @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'edit' }
          format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Неправильные кавычки при вызове `expire_fragment`.

И, если у вас Рельсы версии 4.0 или выше, то достаточно написать:

```
 - cache @post do
```

Оно само обновится при обновлении модели в @post.